# Google Drive API copy shared document from other account

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to copy a shared document from one account to another. Accounts are not in the same domain, so I cannot use domain-wide delegation (https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation.)

When using the Google Drive copy functionality (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) the API considers that the file and ID is located in the Drive of the current user, but that is not the case. I have another Google user who has given read access to everyone on shared document. I also noticed that as other user you can make a copy of that file from the Google Docs UI, but is it possible to do from Google Drive API?

Comment: The scenario you mentioned where a user shares a file and you as the "other" user copy the file from the UI to your own drive, is also possible to do with the API. In this scenario, you as the "other" user performed the action in the UI, it would be the same using the API. You would have to call the copy method to make a copy of the file to your own Drive.

Comment: But the copy action that I also mentioned in my post does not support that. As when I try to copy by supplying fileId to the API, it says that that file is not found. It seems it looks only from the current user Drive.

Comment: Can you access the information of the same file you tried to copy with https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get ?  if you also get a 404 not found it means you don't have access to the file. There is also an option when sharing a file that prevents viewers and commenters to copy, download or print the file.

Comment: Seems to work now Gerardo, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gerardo, it seems it is working as expected. For some reason it had the issue in the beginning, even though the file was shared with the permission "viewable by anyone". Now that I tried it a few days later it seems to work. Maybe some cache stuff on the Google side...